# How to make animation of items for a specific subject's responses over time?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization, gganimate

#### Data

Here is the simulated data for my question. It consists of subjects, items (stimuli), and a T/F response to each item:

```
#### Load Tidyverse ####
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

#### Create Tibble ####
set.seed(123)
subject <- factor(rep(1:5,100))
score <- rbinom(n=500,
                size=1,
                prob=.5)
tib <- tibble(subject,
           score) %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(item = row_number())
tib
```

#### Problem

I'm trying to figure out how to animate either a single subject or many subject responses over time. If I plot the change over time in this way:

```
#### Plot Change Over Items ####
tib %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=item,
             y=score,
             color=subject))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(se=F)
```

[image]

I can at least see generally speaking where the trends lie. However, I would like to have something animated which shows the progression of responses as they happen. I tried using `gganimate`, but it wouldn't use `geom_smooth` and the points alone are lacking a lot of useful information:

```
#### Plot Change Over Items ####
tib %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=item,
             y=score,
             color=subject))+
  geom_point()+
  transition_manual(item)
```

I tried a cumulative sum plot as well:

```
#### Plot Cumulative Sum ####
tib %>% 
  mutate(cum_score = cumsum(score)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=item,
             y=cum_score,
             color=subject))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

But animating it still comes out poor:

```
#### Plot Cumulative Sum ####
tib %>% 
  mutate(cum_score = cumsum(score)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=item,
             y=cum_score,
             color=subject))+
  geom_line()+
  transition_manual(cum_score)
```

Am I messing up the arguments here? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was trying to figure out how to use the `cumulative` argument and I realized it was a logical argument:

```
#### Plot Cumulative Sum ####
tib %>% 
  mutate(cum_score = cumsum(score)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=item,
             y=cum_score,
             color=subject))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  transition_manual(cumulative = T,
                    frames = cum_score)
```

Which gives me a nice gif:

[image]